# Can I stack ongoing action cards on the same base in Smash Up?

Tags: smash-up

In Smash Up, can I play multiple actions on a base?

Comment: multiple different or multiple the same?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless an earlier played action card or minion on the base prohibits that.

In the rules there is a section that states that the rules are not perfect. There will be clashes. And there are some tie-breakers.

1. If rule A prohibits X and rule B grants X, rule A wins.
2. If all else fails, the player whose turn it is decides.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

You're typically limited to one action per turn but you are allowed to play multiple actions on a single base. If you have the cards you can even play multiple of the same action on a single base. The only thing that would inhibit this is if a minion, base or action prevented actions.